# mybatis dynamic sql list in

Tags: java, mybatis

In mybatis, I am trying to generate dynamic sql via the code

```
public String getData(@Param(value = "dataList") List<String> dataList) {

        return new SQL() {
            {
                SELECT("*");
                FROM("data_table");
                WHERE("data_id in (#{dataList})");
            }
        }.toString();
    }
}
```

But this code is not working. In the generated query, it gives only one question mark(?) for list.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("data_id in (");
for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
  if (i > 0) {
    sb.append(',');
  }
  sb.append("#{dataList[").append(i).append("]}");
}
sb.append(')');
WHERE(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. This will greatly improve the quality of your answer, and makes it more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XML.Mybatis official doc shows only xml could use dynamic sql.Code:

```
<select id="getData" resultType="">
    select * from data_table where data_id in
    <foreach item="item" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

detail info see http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html